Movesense Sensor Not Sending Data via Python Script but Works with Mobile App
I am working with a Movesense sensor and attempting to collect data using the Python script provided in the documentation. The path and commands I am using have been verified as correct according to the Movesense API documentation and cross-checked with other reference code. The Python client successfully connects to the sensor and sends the command to start data streaming, but no data is being received.
Here’s what I’ve verified so far:

The sensor is functional, as it streams data when connected to the Movesense mobile app.
The path I am using (e.g., "/Meas/ECG/200") is correct and matches the documentation.
The write command is being sent successfully (confirmed via debug logs), and notifications are enabled without errors.
The UUIDs for the write and notify characteristics are correct.

Despite this, no notifications or data are received via the Python script. I have tried:

Adding delays before and after sending the write command.
Resending the write command multiple times.
Verifying the sensor is not connected to any other device during testing.

The Python script uses the Bleak library for BLE communication. Logging shows no errors, and the sensor acknowledges the write command, but it does not send any data.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or is there something I might be missing in the configuration or communication sequence? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the code that I am using.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Python gatt_sensordata_app client example using the Bleak GATT client.

This example is based on the examples in the Bleak repo: https://github.com/hbldh/bleak
"""

import logging
import asyncio
import platform
import signal
from bleak import BleakClient
from bleak import _logger as logger
from bleak import discover
from functools import reduce
from typing import List
import struct
import sys

WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = (
    <WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID>
)

NOTIFY_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = (
    <NOTIFY_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID>
)


# https://stackoverflow.com/a/56243296
class DataView:
    def __init__(self, array, bytes_per_element=1):
        """
        bytes_per_element is the size of each element in bytes.
        By default we are assume the array is one byte per element.
        """
        self.array = array
        self.bytes_per_element = 1

    def __get_binary(self, start_index, byte_count, signed=False):
        integers = [self.array[start_index + x] for x in range(byte_count)]
        _bytes = [integer.to_bytes(
            self.bytes_per_element, byteorder='little', signed=signed) for integer in integers]
        return reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, _bytes)

    def get_uint_16(self, start_index):
        bytes_to_read = 2
        return int.from_bytes(self.__get_binary(start_index, bytes_to_read), byteorder='little')

    def get_uint_8(self, start_index):
        bytes_to_read = 1
        return int.from_bytes(self.__get_binary(start_index, bytes_to_read), byteorder='little')

    def get_uint_32(self, start_index):
        bytes_to_read = 4
        binary = self.__get_binary(start_index, bytes_to_read)
        return struct.unpack('<I', binary)[0]  # <f for little endian

    def get_int_32(self, start_index):
        bytes_to_read = 4
        binary = self.__get_binary(start_index, bytes_to_read)
        return struct.unpack('<i', binary)[0]  # < for little endian

    def get_float_32(self, start_index):
        bytes_to_read = 4
        binary = self.__get_binary(start_index, bytes_to_read)
        return struct.unpack('<f', binary)[0]  # <f for little endian



async def run_queue_consumer(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        data = await queue.get()
        if data is None:
            logger.info(
                "Got message from client about disconnection. Exiting consumer loop..."
            )
            break
        else:
            # print to stdout
            print(data)

PACKET_TYPE_DATA = 2
PACKET_TYPE_DATA_PART2 = 3
ongoing_data_update = None

async def run_ble_client( end_of_serial: str, sensor_types: List[str], queue: asyncio.Queue):

    # Check the device is available
    devices = await discover()
    
    found = False
    address = None
    for d in devices:
        logger.debug("device:", d)
        if d.name and d.name.endswith(end_of_serial):
            logger.info("device found")
            address = d.address
            found = True
            break

    # This event is set if device disconnects or ctrl+c is pressed
    disconnected_event = asyncio.Event()

    def raise_graceful_exit(*args):
        disconnected_event.set()

    def disconnect_callback(client):
        logger.info("Disconnected callback called!")
        disconnected_event.set()

    async def notification_handler(sender, data):
        """Simple notification handler which prints the data received."""
        logger.info(f"Notification received from {sender}: {data}")
        print(f"Raw data: {data}")
        d = DataView(data)

        packet_type= d.get_uint_8(0)
        reference = d.get_uint_8(1)

        global ongoing_data_update
        # print("packet ", packet_type, ", ongoing:",ongoing_data_update)
        if packet_type == PACKET_TYPE_DATA:
            # ECG (reference 100) fits in one packet
            if reference == 100:
                timestamp = d.get_uint_32(2)
            
                for i in range(0,16):
                    # Interpolate timestamp within the data notification
                    row_timestamp = timestamp + int(i*1000/200)
                    ## ECG package starts with timestamp and then array of 16 samples
                    # Sample scaling is 0.38 uV/sample
                    sample_mV = d.get_int_32(6+i*4) * 0.38 *0.001
                    msg_row = "ECG,{},{:.3f}".format(row_timestamp, sample_mV)
                
                    # queue message for later consumption (output)
                    await queue.put(msg_row)

            else:
            # print("PACKET_TYPE_DATA")
            # Store 1st part of the incoming data
                ongoing_data_update = d
    
        elif packet_type == PACKET_TYPE_DATA_PART2:
            # print("PACKET_TYPE_DATA_PART2. len:",len(data))
                
            # Create combined DataView that contains the whole data packet
            # (skip type_id + ref num of the data_part2)
            d = DataView( ongoing_data_update.array + data[2:])
            ongoing_data_update = None

            # Dig data from the binary
            # msg = "Data: offset: {}, len: {}".format(d.get_uint_32(2), 
            #     len(d.array))
            timestamp = d.get_uint_32(2)
            for i in range(0,8):
                # Interpolate timestamp within the data notification
                row_timestamp = timestamp + int(i*1000/104)
                ## IMU9 package starts with timestamp and then three arrays (len 8*4 bytes) of xyz's 
                ## Each "row" therefore starts (3*4 bytes after each other interleaving to acc, gyro and magn)
                offset = 6 + i * 3* 4
                skip = 3*8*4
                msg_row = "IMU9,{},{:.2f},{:.2f},{:.2f},{:.2f},{:.2f},{:.2f},{:.2f},{:.2f},{:.2f}".format(row_timestamp
                                                            ,  d.get_float_32(offset)
                                                            ,  d.get_float_32(offset+4)
                                                            ,  d.get_float_32(offset+8)
                                                            ,  d.get_float_32(offset+skip+0)
                                                            ,  d.get_float_32(offset+skip+4)
                                                            ,  d.get_float_32(offset+skip+8)
                                                            ,  d.get_float_32(offset+2*skip+0)
                                                            ,  d.get_float_32(offset+2*skip+4)
                                                            ,  d.get_float_32(offset+2*skip+8))
                # queue message for later consumption (output)
                await queue.put(msg_row)

    if found:
        async with BleakClient(address, disconnected_callback=disconnect_callback) as client:

            # Add signal handler for ctrl+c
            signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, raise_graceful_exit)
            signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, raise_graceful_exit)
           
            # Start notifications and subscribe to acceleration @ 13Hz
            logger.info("Attempting to enable notifications")
            await client.start_notify(NOTIFY_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, notification_handler)
            logger.info("Notifications successfully enabled")
            if "ECG" in sensor_types:
                logger.info("Sending write command for ECG")
                await client.write_gatt_char(WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, bytearray([1, 2])+bytearray("/Meas/ECG/200", "utf-8"), response=True)
                logger.info("Write command for ECG sent successfully")
            if "IMU9" in sensor_types:
                logger.info("Sending write command for IMU9")
                await client.write_gatt_char(WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, bytearray([1, 99])+bytearray("/Meas/IMU9/104", "utf-8"), response=True)
                logger.info("Write command for IMU9 sent successfully")

            # Run until disconnect event is set
            await disconnected_event.wait()
            logger.info(
                "Disconnect set by ctrl+c or real disconnect event. Check Status:")

            # Check the conection status to infer if the device disconnected or crtl+c was pressed
            status = client.is_connected
            logger.info("Connected: {}".format(status))

            # If status is connected, unsubscribe and stop notifications
            if status:
                logger.info("Unsubscribe")
                await client.write_gatt_char(WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, bytearray([2, 99]), response=True)
                await client.write_gatt_char(WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, bytearray([2, 100]), response=True)
                logger.info("Stop notifications")
                await client.stop_notify(NOTIFY_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
            
            # Signal consumer to exit
            await queue.put(None)
            
            await asyncio.sleep(1.0)

    else:
        # Signal consumer to exit
        await queue.put(None)
        print("Sensor  ******" + end_of_serial, "not found!")



async def main(end_of_serial: str, sensor_types: List[str]):

    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    client_task = run_ble_client(end_of_serial, sensor_types, queue)
    consumer_task = run_queue_consumer(queue)
    await asyncio.gather(client_task, consumer_task)
    logger.info("Main method done.")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    # print usage if command line arg not given
    if len(sys.argv)<2:
        print("Usage: python movesense_sensor_data <end_of_sensor_name> <sensor_type>")
        print("sensor_type must be either 'IMU9', 'ECG', or omitted to run both")
        exit(1)
    end_of_serial = sys.argv[1]
    sensor_type = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else ""
    

    # Ensure valid sensor type and run the corresponding function
    if sensor_type == "":
        sensor_types = ["IMU9", "ECG"]
    elif sensor_type in ["IMU9", "ECG"]:
        sensor_types = [sensor_type]
    else:
        print("Error: sensor_type must be either 'IMU9' or 'ECG'")
        exit(1)
    asyncio.run(main(end_of_serial, sensor_types))

